# WildFly 9 enable client certificate authentication

Tags: java, ssl, https, wildfly, client-certificates

I want to enable client certificate authentication on my web app running on a WildFly 9 server.

For that, I configured my application with the following elements:

I created a server keystore, a client keystore. From them, I exported a self-signed certificate which I included in my server truststore.

My standalone.xml file contains those parts:

```
...
<management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="my-realm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="server.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
            <authentication>
                <jaas name="my-domain"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
</management>
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
    <security-domains>
        <security-domain name="my-domain" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                </login-module>
                <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag="required">
                    <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/app-users.properties"/>
                    <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/app-roles.properties"/>
                    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                </login-module>
            </authentication>
        </security-domain>
    </security-domains>
</subsystem>
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
        <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="my-realm"/>

        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
    </handlers>
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/9"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
...
```

My web.xml file contains this:

```
...
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin Resource</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
...
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>my-realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>my-role</role-name>
</security-role>
...
```

My jboss-web.xml contains:

```
<security-domain>my-domain</security-domain>
```

I also added the following arguments on my JDK:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=[WILDFLY_HOME]\\standalone\\configuration\\server.truststore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```

Then I tried to access to my web application using a web browser at the URL `http://localhost:8080/my-app-web/`. I am redirected to `https://localhost:8443/my-app-web/` and I can reached the content of the page even if the browser does not contain the client certificate.

Can you tell me what is wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [`Certificate`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Security_Guide/chap-Login_Modules.html#BaseCertLoginModule) login module in your security domain.

Have a look at this [quickstart](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/helloworld-war-ssl) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpful.